# nested loop but avoiding the repetition of first loop

Tags: php

I have two tables; One is *category* and the other one is *sub_category*.

First I want to display all the items in *category* and store the value of each category and then display all the *sub_categories* related to that category but the category should not repeat (it should be displayed only once for all sub-categories).

.[image: this is the output]

```
<?php 
    $abcd = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM categories;");
    while($obj = $abcd->fetch_object())
    {
        $category = $obj->name;
        $results = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `sub-category` WHERE category = '$category';");
        while($omg=$results->fetch_object())
        {
            echo $category. ' '.$omg->subcategory.'<br>';
        }
        echo $omg->subcategory;
    }
?>
```

Comment: change your categories query to something like SELECT * FROM DISTINCT categories

Comment: and learn some sql, it is very powerful skill to write great software, and it is very easy learn http://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp

Comment: @xFighter That will not work. Trivially, there can be multiple subcategories for each category. The `categories` relation already contains unique categories.

Comment: $abcd, $obj, $omg ... Variable naming 101

Comment: but sub category is another table.

Comment: @xFighter And the `categories` table does not contain duplicates. The code is looping over the results from the inner query. While the code can be greatly cleaned up, the comments above are incorrect and non-helpful to answering the OPs question.

Comment: and where is his DDL?

Comment: @xFighter Irrelevant to determining the statement of "use distinct" is invalid.

Comment: so then where is the problem?

Comment: does he want to have something like Automobile : store1, store2, store 3? right?

Comment: @xFighter That seems like reasonable output. Perhaps displayed like a tree. Moving the print of the (parent) category out of the inner loop would address that. Using a single SQL query would be an even bigger improvement - and teach additional concepts the OP may not be familiar with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an array of subcats and implode them so you only get commas where you want them.  Only print the `$category` outside the loop.

```
<?php 
    $abcd = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM categories ");
    while ($obj = $abcd->fetch_object()) {                   
      $category = $obj->name;
      $results = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `sub-category` WHERE category = '$category' ");     

       echo $category.': ';

       $subcats = array();
       while ($omg = $results->fetch_object()) {
         $subcats[] = $omg->subcategory;
       }

       echo implode(',', $subcats).'<br>';
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a simple [JOIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html).

```
<?php 
    $abcd = $mysqli->query('SELECT DISTINCT categories.name,sub-category.subcategory FROM `categories` JOIN `sub-category` ON category.name = categories.category;');
    while($obj = $abcd->fetch_object())
    {
        echo $obj->name.' '.$obj->subcategory.'<br>';
    }
?>
```